# Unable to add attachments to a Jira issue using Power automate

Tags: jira, power-automate

For the internal communication without our organization we're trying to setup a power automate flow to get the data from a microsoft forms form and create a issue in jira.
Using a Jira connector for Power-Automate we're able to create a issue but we're unable to add attachments to that issue.

We've created a Power-Automate flow that follows the following steps:

1. When a response is submitted, This is the trigger. When a response is submitted to the form the power automate flow will trigger.
2. Initialize a variable.
   In order to add multiple attachments to a issue we're creating a array called aAttachments.
3. Apply to each loop.
4. Get response details from form
5. Create jira issue
6. Get attachments from form
7. Insert attachments in a json object.
8. loop trough all the entries in the json
9. Get file contents
10. Add file to array
11. HTTP Post request. Communicatie with the jira rest API and trying to send the file information.

All steps work apart from step 11. We keep getting a 404 return with the following output.

```
Issue doesnt exist or you dont have the right permissions to view the issue.
```

We know the issue exists because the issue is created, and the persmissions needed are open to the public.

This is the Post request:

[image]

What should change in order to add the attachments to the issue created.

Comment: Is the user have enough permission on Jira? I mean, when you login with the API user to the Jira, can you see this specific issue?

Comment: I've tried with multiple accounts, admin, owner, api user with needed perimission

Comment: Can you show us the whole flow diagram?

Comment: 1. Check that your API token is good and it is not revoked by using https://id.atlassian.com/manage/api-tokens endpoint. 2. Check that you're using valid/full  email (or username) during authentication. Check more details in [this article](https://support.atlassian.com/atlassian-account/docs/manage-api-tokens-for-your-atlassian-account/) ('use api token' section)

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

[Issue attachments not getting through for non-admin users via email](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Issue-attachments-not-getting-through-for-non-admin-users-via/qaq-p/1298572)

1 - Navigate to the project where the issues are being created > **Project Settings > Permissions** and check if the user that is creating the issue (Or the default reporter set for your e-mail handler) is configured with the **Create Attachments** permission.

2 - Check if the attachment you are trying to add has the size allowed in your site, under Jira Settings > System > **Attachments**

[Unable to attach files to issues in Jira](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/unable-to-attach-files-to-issues-in-jira-1101927334.html)